# Request mapping not executed

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, broadleaf-commerce

Im not quite sure if this is related to spring or not  :D

I have a form:

```
<form class="csvForm" method="post" action="/admin/myentity/bulkUpload" style="display: none;">
```

and I have a controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/" + AdminMyController.SECTION_KEY)
@Secured("PERMISSION_OTHER_DEFAULT")
public class AdminMyController extends AdminBasicEntityController {
    protected static final String SECTION_KEY = "myentity";

@RequestMapping(value = "/bulkUpload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String showBulkUpload(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model) throws IOException {
  Map<String, Object> responseMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

  return "sts";
  }
}
```

Im wondering why it wont get in showBulkUpload method :o
when I changed the method into GET.. it will get in the method.. Im wondering what did I miss

and btw, there's no issue with the controller bean coz it gets scanned 100%

Comment: are you sure your JSP is getting serialized and submitted? Can you actually see a HTTP GET/POST being generated?

Comment: yup. I have used the developer tools in chrome and checked that the URL is correct and the method is post. btw, I used javascript to submit form. $form.submit()

Comment: How do you know that you are entering the `showBulkUpload` method?

Comment: Well.. I have changed the RequestMethod into GET, and its entering into the method.. how come post wont work?

Comment: `POST` is for submitting data to the server. If you want to view a page use `GET` or leave out the method entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is somewhat related to Spring but is more specific to the CsrfFilter in Broadleaf. I am going to guess that there is a stack trace in your logs from CsrfFilter. This filter (hooked up in applicationContext-security.xml in Broadleaf) will ensure that all POST requests have a csrfToken request parameter (CSRF stands for Cross Site Request Forgery). If you replace the snippet you posted:

```
<form class="csvForm" method="post" action="/admin/myentity/bulkUpload" style="display: none;">
```

With the blc:form Thymeleaf processor (which automatically populates a csrfToken hidden input parameter) into your HTML):

```
<blc:form class="csvForm" method="post" action="/admin/myentity/bulkUpload" style="display: none;">
```

Then it should work.

Comment: Thanks! by the way, how can I get the csrfToken via javascript? Im generating this form in a js file when the user clicks on 'Bulk upload' button

Answer (score 0):

Http **GET** and **POST** methods has different characteristics. As for your case, I just guess about the name you have given, which is `bulkUpload` and you are trying to upload a large amount of data. Http **GET** capacity is limited when you compare it to **POST** method. So if you are trying to upload a large amount of data, then you may not be able send it through **GET** method, up to your browser and server.

**GET** method capacity may change according to client browser as well as your web server. If server cannot process, because of the length of **GET** method, it should raise `414 Request-URI Too Long`.

> The HTTP protocol does not place any a priori limit on the length of
> a URI. Servers MUST be able to handle the URI of any resource they
> serve, and SHOULD be able to handle URIs of unbounded length if they
> provide GET-based forms that could generate such URIs. A server
> SHOULD return 414 (Request-URI Too Long) status if a URI is longer
> than the server can handle (see section 10.4.15).

[Reference](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616)

10.4.15 414 Request-URI Too Long

> The server is refusing to service the request because the
> Request-URI    is longer than the server is willing to interpret. This
> rare    condition is only likely to occur when a client has improperly
> converted a POST request to a GET request with long query
> information, when the client has descended into a URI "black hole" of
> redirection (e.g., a redirected URI prefix that points to a suffix of
> itself), or when the server is under attack by a client attempting to
> exploit security holes present in some servers using fixed-length
> buffers for reading or manipulating the Request-URI.

[Reference](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.4.15)

For client site, browser GET method capacity is as follows:

- **Firefox** No Limit ([Reference](http://wiert.me/2010/04/20/maximum-url-lengths/))
- **IE** 2KB ([Reference](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427))
- **Chrome** No Limit ([Reference](http://wiert.me/2010/04/20/maximum-url-lengths/))

It is highly probable that you use **IE** in your testing, if you cannot access to your Spring Controller. If you are using **Chrome** or **Firefox**, your web server might not handle **GET** method with that long data.

Additional info can be found in [here](http://technomanor.wordpress.com/2012/04/03/maximum-url-size/).